# Disabling touch events when scrolling in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple widgets in my app , which when tapped navigates to the another respective view controllers. these all widgets are been embedded in the scroll view.

the problem is that when I'm scrolling the page eventually when it gets tapped on any widget the page is getting navigated. I want all the touch events to be hidden or paused when user is scrolling the view.

Comment: ***please share the code... I hate this...*** *show what you have tried...* **Hint : use delegates of scrollview.. that's it**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when `scrollView` is drag you can set `setUserInteractionEnabled = NO` ,when end drag you can set `setUserInteractionEnabled = yes`